# Angular 9 chartJs is not updating view after data update

Tags: angular, chart.js, angular9

At the beginning everything works well. This function is called when a time range is selected (LAST_SEVEN_DAYS, LAST_THIRTY_DAYS, etc... ). The function calls the back end and get the result then update the view

```
  loadInstallEvolution(periodRange, label) {

    this.selectedRatingRangeLabel = label;
    const apkIdToUse = sessionStorage.getItem(url.apkIdInUse);
    this.installChartData.datasets[0].data = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    this.installChartData.labels = [];
    this.isLoading = true;
    if (!apkIdToUse) {
      this.isNoDataFound = true;
    } else {
      // tslint:disable-next-line:no-unused-expression
      const param = { historyRange :  periodRange, apkId : Number(apkIdToUse)};
      this.searchApkControllerService.findInstallHistoryUsingGET(param).subscribe(
        (reviewList) => {

          let index = 0;
          let max = 0;
          let firstValue = 0;

          for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(reviewList)) {
            // change the date format
            if (periodRange === 'LAST_SEVEN_DAYS' || periodRange === 'LAST_THIRTY_DAYS' ) {
              key = this.datepipe.transform(key, 'MM/dd');
            }

            this.installChartData.datasets[0].data[index] = value;
            this.installChartData.labels[index] = key;
            // get first value;
            if (index === 0) {
              firstValue = value;
            }
            // calculate the max of y axis
            if (max < value) {
              max = value;
            }
            index++;
          }

          // update the axis
          this.chartDataConfig.areaChartOptions.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.max = max + 20;
          this.chartDataConfig.areaChartOptions.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.beginAtZero = false;
          this.isLoading = false;
        },
        (error) => {
          this.notifications.create(
            'Error',
            error.error.message,
            NotificationType.Error,
            { theClass: 'outline primary', timeOut: 6000, showProgressBar: false }
          );
          this.isLoading = false;
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

Because, I have multiple charts, instead of making multiple calls for each chart, i decided to make one call, then all charts update when a new data is available.

I added then

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.sharevariableService.getApkHistoryDto().subscribe((apkHistory) => {
      if(apkHistory != null) {
        this.loadInstallEvolution(apkHistory);
      }
    });

  }
```

then my function becomes:

```
 loadInstallEvolution(apkHistoryDto: ApkHistoryDto) {

        console.log("loadInstallEvolution apps install");
        const apkIdToUse = sessionStorage.getItem(url.apkIdInUse);
        this.installChartData.datasets[0].data = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
        this.installChartData.labels = [];
        this.isLoading = true;
    
        if (!apkIdToUse) {
          this.isNoDataFound = true;
        } else {
    
    
          let index = 0;
          let max = 0;
          let firstValue = 0;
    
          for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(apkHistoryDto.installHistory)) {
            // change the date format
            if (apkHistoryDto.historyRange === 'LAST_SEVEN_DAYS' || apkHistoryDto.historyRange === 'LAST_THIRTY_DAYS' ) {
              key = this.datepipe.transform(key, 'MM/dd');
            }
    
            this.installChartData.datasets[0].data[index] = value;
            this.installChartData.labels[index] = key;
    
            // get first value;
            if (index === 0) {
              firstValue = value;
            }
            // calculate the max of y axis
            if (max < value) {
              max = value;
            }
            index++;
          }
          // update the axis
          //this.installChartData.datasets[0].data = [...this.installChartData.datasets[0].data];
          console.log(this.installChartData);
          this.chartDataConfig.areaChartOptions.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.max = max + 20;
          this.chartDataConfig.areaChartOptions.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.beginAtZero = false;
          this.isLoading = false;
        }
      }
```

With this new function, my chart is not updated. Variables are set correctly but no way to update view.

in my `app-install-eveolution-chart.component.html` I have:

```
  <app-area-chart [shadow]="true" class="chart" [options]="chartDataConfig.areaChartOptions"
                  [data]="installChartData"></app-area-chart>
```

and the `app-area-chart` is another component
area-chart.component.html

```
<div [class]="class"><canvas #chart></canvas></div>
```

and the `area-chart.component.ts`

```
export class AreaChartComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

  @Input() shadow = false;
  @Input() options;
  @Input() data;
  @Input() class = 'chart-container';
  @ViewChild('chart', { static: true }) chartRef: ElementRef;

  chart: Chart;

  public constructor() {
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = 'white';
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.shadow) {
      Chart.defaults.lineWithShadow = Chart.defaults.line;
      Chart.controllers.lineWithShadow = Chart.controllers.line.extend({
        draw(ease) {
          Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw.call(this, ease);
          const chartCtx = this.chart.ctx;
          chartCtx.save();
          chartCtx.shadowColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.15)';
          chartCtx.shadowBlur = 10;
          chartCtx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
          chartCtx.shadowOffsetY = 10;
          chartCtx.responsive = true;
          chartCtx.stroke();
          Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);
          chartCtx.restore();
        }
      });
    }
    console.log("coding is awesome for brain");
    const chartRefEl = this.chartRef.nativeElement;
    const ctx = chartRefEl.getContext('2d');
    this.chart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: this.shadow ? 'lineWithShadow' : 'line',
      data: this.data,
      options: this.options
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.chart) {
      this.chart.destroy();
    }
  }
}
```

I tried many solution without success.
During testing, with the first old solution, after each new data, I can enter inside `ngAfterViewInit` and have my console.log. With the new solution, i have this just the first time, not when i there is an update, nothing happens.

Please, do you have any idea ?
Any help please ?
Thanks

EDIT:
I tried the solution by using `ngOnInit` in the component to auto detect changes, but this function is still not called.

Comment: finally find a solution.   ngOnInit() {
    this.sharevariableService.getApkHistoryDto().subscribe((apkHistory) => {
      if(apkHistory != null) {
        this.isLoading = true;
        setTimeout (() => {
          this.loadInstallEvolution(apkHistory);
        }, 10);
      }
    });
    
  } and when the loading is true, i show a spinner instead of the gapgh

Answer (score 0):

finally find a solution.

```
  ngOnInit() { 
this.sharevariableService.getApkHistoryDto().subscribe((apkHistory) => { 

 if(apkHistory != null) { 
   this.isLoading = true; setTimeout (() => { 
     this.loadInstallEvolution(apkHistory); 
 }, 10); } 

}); }
```

and when the loading is true, i show a spinner instead of the gapgh